# Error when executing OpenMPI code (OPAL Error) with nvcc

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi, openmpi, nvcc, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to run OpenMPI code on a NVIDIA Jetson TX2. But I am getting an OPAL Error when i run `mpiexec`.

Compilation instruction:

```
$ nvcc -I/home/user/.openmpi/include/ -L/home/user/.openmpi/lib/ -lmpi -std=c++11 *.cu *.cpp -o program
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
```

Execution error message:

```
$ mpiexec -np 4 ./program 
[user:05728] OPAL ERROR: Not initialized in file pmix2x_client.c at line 109
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[user:05728] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
[user:05729] OPAL ERROR: Not initialized in file pmix2x_client.c at line 109
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[user:05729] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[7361,1],0]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I installed OpenMPI version 3.1.2 using the following instructions:

```
$ ./configure --prefix="/home/user/.openmpi" --with-cuda
$ make; sudo make install
```

I have also setup my `$PATH` and my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables accordingly based on instructions from this [link](http://lsi.ugr.es/jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf)

I am able to successfully execute the program on my laptop (Intel i7). Upon looking up the error I found some links suggesting that I reinstall OpenMPI. I have tried doing so multiple times (including a fresh download of the library) without any success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edits**

I tried running the following Minimal code (`main.cpp`) as asked in the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  std::cout << rank << '\n';
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

To compile this, I reran the previous command and got the same error:

```
$ nvcc -I/home/user/.openmpi/include/ -L/home/user/.openmpi/lib/ -lmpi -std=c++11 main.cpp -o program
```

But then if i compile it with `mpic++` it is able to run perfectly fine.

```
$ mpic++ main.cpp -o ./program
$ mpiexec -np 4 ./program 
0
1
3
2
```

Comment: can you `mpiexec -n 4 hello_c` ? the source is in `examples/hello_c.c`

Comment: What do you do priori to MPI_INIT?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher only declare rank and size. My main function starts as follows: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int rank, size;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);`. I do `#include` some other `.cu` and `.cpp` files used throughout, but I assume that you only wanted what happens in the main before the `MPI_Init()` call.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet see edits

Comment: Could be that nvcc doesn't link to the proper .so? Try directly /home/user/.openmpi/lib/libmpi.so

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher See edits

Comment: can you upload a [MCVE] so the issue can be investigated ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet see edits. I presume that now we can definitely say that the error is with how the `nvcc` is compiling the program?

Comment: I just want to reiterate that I installed OpenMPI then exact same way on 2 other Intel i7 PCs and I was able to run the code wthout any problems on both of them. I get this error on the **Jetson TX2**.

Answer (score 3):

Is this the **only** version of OpenMPI that you have installed? My guess is that you're using different MPI versions between your build and run. Check `which mpirun` and also search for instances of `mpirun`. If you're on Ubuntu do

```
sudo updatedb
locate mpirun
```

If you call the correct `mpirun` (the same version used to build) then the error should go away.